# OP is unable to accept an answer because the question has been closed?

Tags: support, specific-question

I've given an answer on this question: [Determine whether all radio button groups have one checked box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947446/determine-whether-all-radio-button-groups-have-one-checked-box)

It was closed before, but I've rephrased the question better and voted to reopen it.

However, in the meantime the OP claims that they want to accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947508/1338292) but is unable to do so. Verbatim comment:

> Yes I want to accept this answer. It seems the tick-box you mentioned just isn't there. Perhaps because this question has been closed?

I would say that's not possible; is it?

Comment: OP is probably not logged in or logged in under a different user.

Comment: @juergend but how are they able to write a comment to my answer under the correct user name?

Comment: I just checked a closed question I have, and I still see the checkmark tick next to every answer. Mine was closed as duplicate, so maybe it works differently with that close reason, but I suspect this user was just not looking in the right place. (Looking through their questions list, they have not accepted any answers, which is some more evidence pointing towards that hypothesis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless the *answer* is *locked*, the asker can still accept it (after the mandatory 15-minute waiting period).

Might want to give her a link to https://stackoverflow.com/about - there's an animation there that demonstrates this, and as an added bonus it uses the Stack Overflow styles (unlike How To Ask) so it might be slightly less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!